# EditText setError messed up on Samsung phones

Tags: android, android-edittext

So currently only reproducible on a Samsung S5 and a Galaxy note, this is what my EditText setError is 
[image]

The thing is, I've tried setError on an empty application with an EditText field and it works 100% fine, so it's nothing that Samsung is intrinsically messing up with their libraries. But it does seem like it has to do with how they render their views? I've tested it on a Moto X and other non-samsung phones (including nexus 7 tablet) and it works fine!

When I click away and then back into the EditText, it then "messes" up again to this:
[image]

However, when I click and open the keyboard, rotate the screen into landscape, then back into portrait with the keyboard still up, the setError comes back to normal like so:
[image]

So I'm thinking it has to do with how we render our views or some boundary somewhere. I've already tried requestLayout(), forceLayout(), and invalidate() the view on edittext. Also tried invalidate() on the whole view. Still nothing. Any ideas/where to investigate? Thanks all

EDIT: Here's the XML Layout for the just the LinearLayout stuff

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/location_padding_top"
              android:paddingBottom="100dp"
        >

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="Zip Code"
            android:maxLength="5"
            android:textSize="@dimen/field_text_size"
            android:layout_weight="2"

            />
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/my_location_image"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_gps_blue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Updated @GreyBeardedGeek